# Definition of improper divisor in algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

My textbook on algebra states these definitions:

$R$ - Commutative integral domain with unity, where integral domain means $xy = 0 \Rightarrow x= 0 $ or $y=0$

Two elements $a,b \in R$ are called associates if there exists a unit $u \in R$ such that $a = bu$.

An element $b \in R$ is called an improper divisor of an elemenent $a \in R$ if $b$ is either a unit or an associate of $a$.

Later it says for irreducible $a$: "Every divisor of $a$ is improper, i.e. $a=bc$ implies either $b$ or $c$ is a unit.

For this to make sense it would seem that if $a = bc$, where $b$ is an associate of $a$, then $c$ must be a unit.  Is this obvious from the definition?

Comment: You seem to be implicitly assuming that $\,a\,$ is irreducible in the "Later" statement.

Comment: Ah, yes. I did not mean "For every $a$ that is not a unit", I meant " For such $a$, where $a$ btw is not a unit"

Comment: Usually irreducibles are nonunits by definition, so something still seems fishy. You are trying to show irreducibles have no proper factors, right?

Comment: Well, I see that I am unclear here, it is actually part of the definiton I am asking about. I was just making sure that the notion of proper in the definition coincided with the definition of proper given above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a = bc$ where $b$ is an associate of $a$, then $a = bu$ for some unit $u$. So $bc = bu$, so $bcu^{-1} = b$, so $b(1 - cu^{-1}) = 0$. So if $b$ is nonzero (and the last statement is obviously not true if $a = b = 0$) then since $R$ is a domain, $1 - cu^{-1} = 0$, and so $c = u$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\,\ a = bc \!\iff\! \dfrac{b}a = \dfrac{1}c\ $ so $\,\ a\mid b\!\iff\! c\mid 1,\,$ i.e. $\ b\,$ is associate to $\,a\!\iff\! c\,$ is a unit

Comment: Does the notation $\frac{b}{a}$ make sense when we don't know that $a$ is a unit?

Comment: @Improve Yes, because every domain has a fraction field. If you don't know about fraction fields then you can clear the denominators. But the fractional form makes the essence of the equivalence crystal clear, which is why I presented it that way.

Comment: I am not familiar with fraction fields, but I shall look it up.